# Is their any Direct bank to bank Transfer Third party API available?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

I want to integrate **Direct bank to bank transfer for local and international account**. I have almost tested 4-5 API but still didn't get proper third party API for that. Do you have any information regarding this. Please share with me.

My Actual task is any user can transfer money to other user account without creating account in third party website.like Stripe, PayPal

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For direct bank to bank transfer use TransferWise third party sdk which is cheaper and easy to integrate.

**Benefits of TransferWise Sdk:**

- Provide your customers faster and cheaper cross-border payments,
  compared to traditional SWIFT alternatives.
- Offer competitive, fair, and transparent pricing to customers at the
  mid-market exchange rate.
- Reduce your operational costs of cross-border payments.
- Stop losing out on cross-border revenues because your customers are
  finding better alternatives.

**Some of TransferWise bank partners**

1. Monzo in the United Kingdom
2. N26 in Germany
3. LHV in Estonia
4. BPCE in France

[Visit This Link](https://transferwise.github.io/api-docs-banks/#transferwise-for-banks-api-integration-guide)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it's possible with Stripe now.

Here is the link to choose the suitable option for you: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/bank-debits-transfers?lang=node

Comment: For that every user has to registered in bank like paypal. I already tested with this its not working with stripe.

Comment: No, you would not need paypal, they already has that option surely if you're operating in Europe Stripe SEPA